# Return X amount(s) of cell values under under specific cell address

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

To start, thanks for reading, I will be leaving [this picture here](https://i.ibb.co/6Wwq3JN/image.png), which is what my current sheet looks like.

I'm trying to parse the information on A:A so that every instance of "X/Y", where X and Y are the values before and after the separator, is converted to a column title and I get X cell values below it. I currently have a column with all the results passed through data validation to create a drop list.

For example, A4 contains the original string, I then passed it through this formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("* - *", A:A)), MATCH(ROW(A:A), ROW(A:A)), ""), ROWS(A:A)))
```

with this I get the value on C2. C2 is then passed through this formula:

```
=MID(RIGHT(C2,FIND("/",C2)+2),FIND("-",C2)-1,LEN(C2))
```

which I get the value on F2, and then again through this:

```
=MID(F2, FIND("/",F2)-1,1)
```

to get the value on G2.
(If you can somehow merge all this into 1, I will surely appreciate it)

Now, what I've been trying to do is the following, I will explain with an example.
G2 is 2, which means I want to get the 2 cell values under A4, but I'm only managing to get A5, not A5 AND A6.

I'm currently doing this in Google Sheets as I found it a little easier since I don't have access to MS Office 365, and only have 2019 installed.

[This](https://i.ibb.co/7zvMkSH/image.png) is what I currently have working, and [this](https://i.ibb.co/rdTKyH8/image.png) is what I would like to have as an end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make the formula that resolves my problem. It's the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDEX(C:C,Sheet1!C1),A:A,0)+1,1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDEX(C:C,Sheet1!C1),A:A,0)+INDEX(I:I,Sheet1!C1),1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" · ",INDIRECT(INDEX(F:F,Sheet1!C1))))))
```

Using `MATCH(INDEX(Range,Cell)` I was able to procedurally change the range and position values of the outermost `INDEX` to be able to return custom ranged tables when needed.`Sheet1!C1` contains a `ROW` formula, which return the row position of the section I'm looking for, which is used as an index to return cell positions on `C` and `F` on `Sheet2`.

[Final result](https://i.ibb.co/7rh60Hc/image.png)